# Check CMake's option in C++ source

Tags: c++, g++, cmake

I have the following option defined in CMake:

```
option(OURAPP-DEV-USE_EXTREME_DEBUGGING "Use extreme debugging features" OFF)
```

and I would like to check in a C++ file that this option was checked (in the CMake-GUI) or not.

I.e. writing C++ code like:

```
#if OURAPP-DEV-USE_EXTREME_DEBUGGING
 print_extra_debugging();
#endif
```

Please note, that our project setup requires that there is a `-` between the options regarding the components (such as OURAPP and DEV and the rest ...)

Any idea how to make it happen?

Comment: C preprocessor macros (and C++ macros as well) cannot use hyphens in their names. CMake may allow an option name like that, but I would expect it would modify it before turning it into a C macro (probably by replacing hyphens with underscores), but I don't have a copy of the CMake manual available at the moment...

Comment: @twalberg: CMake does not automatically export anything as defines. You have to tell it explicitly (and than you get to name it as you want).

Comment: @JanHudec Right - I'm a bit of a novice on CMake... My point was more about the `#if` construct (which should probably have been `#ifdef` in any case), regardless of how CMake got to that point...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transfer the CMake option to the C++ world using a preprocessor define.

```
IF(OURAPP-DEV-USE_EXTREME_DEBUGGING)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUSE_EXTREME_DEBUGGING)
ENDIF()
```

Under the hood, this adds the define to the compiler command line, and is then available to the preprocessor:

```
#ifdef USE_EXTREME_DEBUGGING
    print_extra_debugging();
#endif
```

Note that a hyphen is not a valid character in a C preprocessor token, so you'll have to change the name in the define.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cmake `CONFIGURE_FILE`, cf. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3Aconfigure_file